# How to implement Branch.io in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, branch.io

I am trying to implement a referral program in my windows phone application. Where a user shares a link in some social site and gets reward points if someone installs the app using his/her link. For android and/or iOS, developers can use Branch.io SDK for retrieving the information of the referrer. Now, I couldn't find any instructions on how to do it in a windows phone app in their official website. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: It looks like Branch.io is not available for windows phone. Is there any alternative to Branch.io for wp platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: Windows Phone has [around 0.4% market share](https://www.statista.com/statistics/266136/global-market-share-held-by-smartphone-operating-systems/), so we don't currently offer an SDK for that platform. It's possible you could roll your own 'mini SDK' using our [REST API](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api) for just the functions you need.

Sorry not to have better news!

Comment: Windows apps also run on Windows 10 and Surface.